App Storage Size Increases with CoreML or Metal Usage on iOS
Update
I got reply on Apple Developer Forum CoreML - doUnloadModel:options:qos:error, and the issue is probably with tflite's CoreML delegate implementation.
Question
I'm encountering an issue where the app's storage size increases each time tflite model is loaded, and the storage doesn't clear afterward. Specifically, I'm using the PoseNet TensorFlow Lite model on iPhone to demonstrate the problem.
This video shows the 'PoseEstimation' app storage size increasing when I switch between the models: https://imgur.com/a/T8PSNTe
I have another model running with Metal or CoreML, where the app's storage size increases by ~300MB every time the model is loaded. Over time, this causes the storage size to grow to several gigabytes, eventually filling the phone's storage to the point where the app can no longer open.
I attempted to clear the app's storage each time it launches using the method described in How to clear Cache in iOS?, but this approach didn't resolve the issue.
Related Posts:

SwiftUI Demo APP and CoreML -> increases app file size
Loading CoreML model increases app size?

I get the following warning log whenever the model is re-loaded or the app is closed. this warning might be related to the storage issue:
doUnloadModel:options:qos:error:: model=_ANEModel: { modelURL=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B95DFE34-2664-44E6-A76F-8655EF500E5D/tmp/1D6F1D57-6B7B-4810-9DCC-DBA115104D14-9816-000005716C16268D.mlmodelc/ : sourceURL= (null) : key={"isegment":0,"inputs":{"0_62":{"shape":[257,257,1,3,1]}},"outputs":{"110_0":{"shape":[9,9,1,34,1]},"109_0":{"shape":[9,9,1,17,1]},"112_0":{"shape":[9,9,1,32,1]},"111_0":{"shape":[9,9,1,32,1]}}} : identifierSource=0 : cacheURLIdentifier=D57E9D7D928A79F85793927E324F52140B1517B87B8E491CD2C5BACD02351EEE_3FB4BC7D39229579590186066A34502862A58CA73B7B7C276A9AA0F535B53525 : string_id=0x00000000 : program=_ANEProgramForEvaluation: { programHandle=5984711941790 : intermediateBufferHandle=5984712028205 : queueDepth=127 } : state=3 : programHandle=5984711941790 : intermediateBufferHandle=5984712028205 : queueDepth=127 : attr={
    ANEFModelDescription =     {
        ANEFModelInput16KAlignmentArray =         (
        );
        ANEFModelOutput16KAlignmentArray =         (
        );
        ANEFModelProcedures =         (
                        {
                ANEFModelInputSymbolIndexArray =                 (
                    0
                );
                ANEFModelOutputSymbolIndexArray =                 (
                    0,
                    1,
                    2,
                    3
                );
                ANEFModelProcedureID = 0;
            }
        );
        kANEFModelInputSymbolsArrayKey =         (
            "0_62"
        );
        kANEFModelOutputSymbolsArrayKey =         (
            "109_0@output",
            "110_0@output",
            "111_0@output",
            "112_0@output"
        );
        kANEFModelProcedureNameToIDMapKey =         {
            net = 0;
        };
    };
    NetworkStatusList =     (
                {
            LiveInputList =             (
                                {
                    BatchStride = 444096;
                    Batches = 1;
                    Channels = 3;
                    Depth = 1;
                    DepthStride = 444096;
                    Height = 257;
                    Interleave = 1;
                    Name = "0_62";
                    PlaneCount = 3;
                    PlaneStride = 148032;
                    RowStride = 576;
                    Symbol = "0_62";
                    Type = Float16;
                    Width = 257;
                }
            );
            LiveOutputList =             (
                                {
                    BatchStride = 9792;
                    Batches = 1;
                    Channels = 17;
                    Depth = 1;
                    DepthStride = 9792;
                    Height = 9;
                    Interleave = 1;
                    Name = "109_0@output";
                    PlaneCount = 17;
                    PlaneStride = 576;
                    RowStride = 64;
                    Symbol = "109_0@output";
                    Type = Float16;
                    Width = 9;
                },
                                {
                    BatchStride = 19584;
                    Batches = 1;
                    Channels = 34;
                    Depth = 1;
                    DepthStride = 19584;
                    Height = 9;
                    Interleave = 1;
                    Name = "110_0@output";
                    PlaneCount = 34;
                    PlaneStride = 576;
                    RowStride = 64;
                    Symbol = "110_0@output";
                    Type = Float16;
                    Width = 9;
                },
                                {
                    BatchStride = 18432;
                    Batches = 1;
                    Channels = 32;
                    Depth = 1;
                    DepthStride = 18432;
                    Height = 9;
                    Interleave = 1;
                    Name = "111_0@output";
                    PlaneCount = 32;
                    PlaneStride = 576;
                    RowStride = 64;
                    Symbol = "111_0@output";
                    Type = Float16;
                    Width = 9;
                },
                                {
                    BatchStride = 18432;
                    Batches = 1;
                    Channels = 32;
                    Depth = 1;
                    DepthStride = 18432;
                    Height = 9;
                    Interleave = 1;
                    Name = "112_0@output";
                    PlaneCount = 32;
                    PlaneStride = 576;
                    RowStride = 64;
                    Symbol = "112_0@output";
                    Type = Float16;
                    Width = 9;
                }
            );
            Name = net;
        }
    );
} : perfStatsMask=0}  was not loaded by the client.

The warning seems like a key clue. I checked the app’s storage in the Xcode file inspector, and the file path in the warning matches what’s shown there

